Why is thermal conductivity of thermal interface materials so low?
I need to reduce the heating of a battery that is inside a device with metal casing. I was thinking of using the metal casing as a heat sink. To do so, I need to use a thermal interface material (TIM) between the battery and the metal cover. There is about 2 mm gap between the battery and the metal cover.
It seems all the TIMs I find have a thermal conductivity between 1 and 5. For example:

1.6 W/(m*K): https://docs.rs-online.com/a842/A700000008000632.pdf
4 W/(m*K): https://befr.rs-online.com/web/p/thermal-pads/7074689

Does it mean that 1-5 W/m.K is a very good thermal conductivity? Isn't it supposed to be much higher, so that it can transfer the maximum heat to the heat sink? Also, what is considered to be a good thermal conductivity for an insulator TIM?

Good question, I would have the same problem if I tried searching for a solution because I have no idea what they mean by "m.K", sometimes written as "mK" but I guess it's not millikelvin?

It should be in paretheses, W/(mK) (meter, not milli), but the unit is well enough known that shortcuts are often taken. See also: "BTUs" (implied: BTU/hr).

W/m.K is discussed here where someone says: "W/mK stands for Watts per meter-Kelvin."

Is your battery an odd shape or have uneven surface? It may be better to have "TIM" that is flexible and can conform to fill the 2mm gap with no airspace. Any rigid "TIM" leaves air gaps that impair thermal transfer.

So how do you stop the heat getting into the battery? Heat moves based on temperature difference ie higher to lower temperature...

Perhaps you need to consider forced ventilation where that air gap may be useful...

Those figures are much better than air, much worse than metals. A flexible TIM conforms to the surfaces eliminating air-spaces. Air stirred by a fan is much better than stationary air.

In nature, electrically insulating = bad thermal conductivity. I don't know why, but they are linked. Something-something-electrons? The commercial TIMs tend to be the best tradeoff between electrically insulating and thermally conductive available.

Is your battery not encased in plastic? You could just use a piece of metal to fill the gap if so, with thermal paste for better conductivity. But the battery might not conduct heat internally all that well.

@winny There are a few exceptions to this: Aluminum nitride, beryllium oxide, and diamond all have thermal conductivities comparable to metals (diamond significantly better than metals) while being electrically insulating, but they have their own issues (AlN is not very chemically resistant, BeO is extremely toxic, and diamond is extremely expensive). They are also all very hard materials that can't conform to fill crevices.

@winny Yes, metals for example contain an electron gas (more or less) which has excellent thermal and electrical conductivity. The rules for insulators are less clear, as electron flow obviously isn't doing the business, and yet the most (thermally) conductive materials (diamond) are several times better than the best metal (silver). This is a historically (and still, though perhaps to a lesser extent) interesting topic in condensed-matter physics. :)

@Hearth Yes, otherwise we wound't have TIMs. I was thinking in general, stuff you find in nature. Stone, wood, glass, all are good electrical insulators and have low thermal conductivity. Metals are the opposite. Mankind had to engineer materials to sit in-between. Perhaps mica would be one of the better materials found in nature.

@TimWilliams Ah! So it was electrons all along. The spice mélange of EEs.

you might consider trying to cool the whole case, with internal heatsinks stuck to the inside of the case that move ambient heat into the case and out the other side. Adding airflow would help a lot as well. That maximizes the conduction area of the battery through it's existing case, and doesn't hurt the other electronics either.

Could you insulate the battery from the rest of the inside of the case? Possibly in addition to adding a thermal pad to the case.

AIUI, the hotter a battery gets, the faster it degrades and the shorter its useful life.  Does your battery need to get so hot in the first place?

@winny a lot of heat is carried by electrons, especially in metals.  There are other important heat transport processes in crystalline materials (phonons, i.e. lattice vibrations), which is why diamond is an electrical insulator and a good thermal conductor; these are relevant in a lot of semiconductors

It's hard to make it better than 10 W m-1 K-1 or so, the lower end of solid materials. Al2O3 (sapphire) for example is only about 40, polycrystalline (your standard alumina ceramic parts) maybe 20-30.
Special ceramics (AlN and BeO most famously) can do much more.
Metals are typically quite good: say from lead (~35) to steel (~80) to aluminum (~200) and copper (~400).  (The fact that metals are both electrically and thermally conductive (and about in even proportion across most all metals) is no coincidence (i.e. due to motion of free electrons).)
The clear standout is carbon, as pyrolytic graphite (in-plane) and diamond boast conductivity over 2000 W m-1 K-1.
But none of this matters when other materials must be bonded together.  Thermal conductivity is maximized with a pure metallurgical joint, and even then, heat doesn't flow perfectly: there is a small temperature drop due to a single boundary between dissimilar materials.  The corresponding resistance is small, but if we can't have a single boundary but have to have thousands, or millions, of boundaries inbetween, the bulk conductivity goes down quickly.
Such is the case for thermal interface materials.  Typically an oil or polymer filler is used to achieve a soft, conformable consistency, and it may be a liquid or paste (grease), or have some elasticity to it (SIL PAD(R) and relatives).  Pastes up to 15 W m-1 K-1 or so are available, but most are just a few W m-1 K-1.
Since the filler needed for a mostly-flat heatsink joint is small (100s µm or below), a relatively low conductivity has little effect over the wide area of the joint; along with low cost, and ease of assembly, this is why thermal pastes are standard practice for heatsinking of conduction-cooled components like power transistors and CPUs.
Gap-filling pads, and other rubber, self-adhesive, phase-change and bonding materials, can't (or shouldn't) be squished down as far, and thus trade additional thermal resistance for a wider conformation range: they can be used directly on PCBs loaded with SMT components, for example, filling in the gaps between and sinking heat both directly from components, along their leads, and through copper on the PCB itself.
Thermal conductivity is also relative.  You can have a plastic-body component, bonded directly to a solid-diamond water-cooled heatsink, and see essentially zero improvement over conventional TIMs and heatsink materials.  In particular, your battery probably has relatively poor conductivity; but how, exactly, is an interesting question.
Rather than digress into anisotropic structures and vapor-phase mechanisms, I'd rather emphasize first: batteries aren't supposed to get hot, and either something is making it hot (consider sinking heat from that item directly), or it's being used rather harshly (consider using a better rated battery, or limiting the peak power delivery of the system).

From the wording of OP's question, I'm wondering if their battery's heating up because the small amount of heat it's producing's having a hard time escaping and's instead accumulating in the battery compartment?

Perhaps. It's something to look into, in any case.


Does it mean that 1-5 W/m.K is a very good thermal conductivity ?

For something that isn't solid metal, yes, it's a pretty good value!
The thing is, you're not "supposed to" have thick layers of thermal interface material. It's there to solve the problem of surface roughness. That is: without some kind of interface material, two "flat" surfaces facing each other have a lot less contact area (and therefore a lot less thermal conductivity) than you would expect, because only the "high points" of the surfaces are actually in contact, and the rest of the space between them is filled with air. TIM fills those tiny gaps with something that, while it has worse conductivity than metal, is much better than air. A thickness of 0.1 - 0.2 mm is about right for that purpose.  Any thicker and the overall thermal conductivity goes down.
If you use it to fill in a larger space than that, then you can still say "well, it's better than air". Or plastic.

An ideal thermal interface material would have the following properties:

High thermal conductivity to improve heat transfer.
High electrical resistivity so you don't short out your electronics.
Mechanically compliant so it fills any gaps without applying load to your electronics.

Here is a plot of thermal conductivity versus electrical resistivity from CES Selector Version 4.7.0 for 2799 bulk materials:

As you can see, thermal conductivity ranges from 19 mW / m K to 422 W / mK, and electrical resistivity spans more than twenty five orders of magnitude. Taking a quick tour, in the upper left are high thermal conductivity / low electrical resistivity materials such as silver and oxygen free copper. The red band on the left are metals. Low thermal conductivity / low electrical resistivity materials such as carbon filled foams are in the lower left. In the lower right are low thermal conductivity / high electrical resistivity materials that are mostly unfilled polymer foams.
From the first two bullet points, you would think the ideal thermal interface material is in the upper right of the plot (high thermal conductivity / high electrical resistivity materials):

From the plot one would say Beryllia (99%) is the ideal material with thermal conductivity of 300 W / m K and electrical resistivity of 10 TOhm m, except it's toxic. Other materials such as diamond, sapphire, and aluminum nitride are expensive. None of materials in the upper right are mechanically compliant. Plotting thermal conductivity versus Young's modulus for all the materials:

From the above plot you can see that there aren't a lot of good thermal conductors that are mechanically compliant, regardless of electrical resistivity. Note that my version of CES Selector is from 2006, and doesn't contain high conductivity graphite which is probably an exception to what I just said.
The work around is to mix a high thermal conductivity material with a high electrical resistivity material that is mechanically compliant. For example one can mix alumina (about 23 W / m K) with a polymer or rubber. You improve mechanical compliance, maintain electrical resistivity, but at the expense of thermal conductivity.
So is 1 W / m K to 5 W / m K is a very good thermal conductivity material? Not compared to other materials. Are they they good thermal interface materials? They aren't bad, but you can find better ones on Digikey.
